# Can't open FileInputStream from assets

Tags: android, android-assets

I am trying to open a file from the assets as a `FileInputStream` using

```
new FileInputStream("file:///android_asset/file.html");
```

But it always throws a `FileNotFoundException`, even thought the file **is** there.

I know I can open files from assets using `getAssets()` and so on (and this works for the same file), but shouldn't this method be also working?

PS. I have set my app to request permission for file accessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assets are stored relative to your app location and that is why absolute paths will not work. You need to use `AssetManager` to retrieve an `InputStream` to your assets as needed. `getAssets()` should work just fine.

Comment: But I do remember accessing assets with that URI pattern. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I can't comment on that without knowing exactly under which conditions you were able to do it but I would suggest sticking with the officially supported way to avoid bugs etc.

Comment: **Assets are not files.**  The `file:///android_asset/` pattern works only in settings (like a WebView) where it will be trapped and converted back to the unique **non-File** API by which Assets are exposed at runtime.  You cannot use it in a situation where a path to an actual File is required.